# how i can do drop down selection in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, dropdown

> I want the drop down selection
>
> but it is showing with radio button in ionic 3.
>
> [Stackbiz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xvwyxs?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)
>
> how can i do drop down selection (with text).

Ref : [Refered link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#select)

Ioinc v3

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming" interface="popover" >
      <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image: row coloumn]

Comment: Your Refered link redirect to slides. Please help with correct link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop Down selection is device-specific. In android device, it will show as radio button icon and in ios device, it will show as selection icon.

Comment: glad to help you